# MS-Access application in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, ms-access, tfs

How can I add and Access 2013 application in Visual Studio so in that way I can add it to Source Control TFS and the keep track of changes ?

I could create a solution and any project with a folder and then add the files but I am wondering if it is a better way.

This is not the same question of "[MS-Access 2013 with Team Foundation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31328788/ms-access-2013-with-team-foundation-server)" that is talking about adding plugin to Access 2013 because that plugin cost. This is more how to create a work around with VS adding the access application to TFS as regular files inside a VS project or solution.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MS-Access 2013 with Team Foundation Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31328788/ms-access-2013-with-team-foundation-server)

Answer (score -1):

You wouldn't write an Access application in anything else than Access itself. You can write an *add-in* in VS with the Office Tools, but that's about it.

Comment: I actually don't want to write it on Visual Studio I want to add to source control from Visual Studio

Comment: That is not possible. What is possible, however, is to use the add-in that connects Access to Visual SourceSafe if, of course, you have access to a Visual SourceSafe Server. Even then, this is reported to not work reliably. The best and simplest method is simply to create a zip of your accdb file at least once a day and append a time stamp like yyyy-mm-dd hhss to the filename of the zip.