# MS-Access 2013 with Team Foundation Server

Tags: tfs, ms-access-2013

I have access database with form and report that I am changing over time in different scenarios. I would like to be able to track changes and branch modifications.

How can I add MS-Access application to TFS?

Comment: Add it to source control just like you would add any other file. What's the problem here?

Comment: @DanielMann: The problem is that is managed as a large binary file, instead of separate text files as it would be preferable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Disclosure: I am the owner of the product mentioned in the answer.**

As there is little merit in adding the whole mdb/accdb-file to version control, you will need to extract the Access objects (forms, reports, etc.) as files to the filesystem. This can be done by using the `Application.SaveAsText` method. You can later import those files back into your Application with the `LoadFromText` method. - The resulting files can be added to and managed by any version control system using the client of the SCC-System.

This approach is somewhat cumbersome though.

Until Access 2010 Mircosoft provided a [source code control add in for Access](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=6840) that did exactly that and interacted with the version control system to manage the individual objects (as files) there. - This add-in [was discontinued with Access 2013](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Discontinued-features-and-modified-functionality-in-Access-2013-bc006fc3-5b48-499e-8c7d-9a2dfef68e2f).

For Access 2013 and 2016 I only know of one replacement product for the discontinued add-in, which works with TFS (and many other source code control systems). It is named *[Ivercy](http://www.ivercy.com)* and is a commercial product that has been released in September 2015. ***I am it's owner.***

Comment: I signed but I never received the email to get the beta version

Comment: @Devsined: I just sent you an email. If get's lost again, please get in touch via the email-adr on my website.

Comment: The link to Team Explorer 2013 is dead https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=40776

Comment: @Apocatastasis: Thank you bringing this to my attention. I filed a support request with Microsoft to resolve this issue.

Comment: @Apocatastasis: We updated the links on our site. You now need a free Visual Studio Dev Essentials Account to download Team Explorer 2013.